# How to give custom activation function to Conv2DNormActivation

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, torch, activation, activation-function

As it seems `torchvision.ops.Conv2dNormActivation` function only takes the Activation functions defined under `torch.nn` due to the declaration of the `activation_layer` argument as `Callable[..., torch.nn.Module]` in the [source code](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/_modules/torchvision/ops/misc.html#Conv2dNormActivation).

I tried defining a custom activation function (example) like

```
class ExpExp(nn.Module):
    __constants__ = ['inplace']
    inplace: bool
    def __init__(self,inplace: bool = False):
        super(TanhExp, self).__init__()
  
    def forward(self, x):
        return x*torch.exp(torch.exp(x))
    
    def extra_repr(self): 
        inplace_str = 'inplace=True' if self.inplace else ''
        return inplace_str
```

Has called it as

```
Conv2dNormActivation(
                    in_channels,
                    out_channels,
                    kernel_size=(h,w),
                    stride=stride,
                    padding = padding,
                    norm_layer=norm_layer,
                    activation_layer=ExpExp(),
                    inplace=None
                ))
```

It returned an error `TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'`

I think I have to give input `x` to the `ExpExp()` activation function when calling it in the `Conv2dNoemActivation`. But how do I do that? Is there a way we can specify custom activation function?